# Cannot order result by name in descending order using Dynamic 365 Web API

Tags: sorting, dynamics-crm

I'm using the following 2 queries to retrieve a list of account records from Dynamic 365 using its Web API:

```
https://<CRM URL>/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$orderby=accountid asc&$select=accountid,name
```

And

```
https://<CRM URL>/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$orderby=accountid desc&$select=accountid,name
```

I expected that the first query will get me all account records sorted by name attribute in ascending order, while the second query will get me all records sorted by name attribute in descending order. However, in both query, some records are not getting sorted.

I'm using Dynamic 365 Online, Version 1612 (8.2.2.111).

I also tried with team entity with the following query and yet the result was sorted in ascending order.

```
https://<CRM URL>/api/data/v8.2/teams?$orderby=name desc&$select=teamid,name
```

Sample data for team:

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897395\"",
    "teamid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TeamTest2",
    "ownerid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894834\"",
    "teamid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TestingPl13",
    "ownerid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897396\"",
    "teamid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1",
    "name": "TeamTest3",
    "ownerid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894835\"",
    "teamid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078",
    "name": "kalinin-staging",
    "ownerid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078"
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894834\"",
    "teamid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TestingPl13",
    "ownerid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897396\"",
    "teamid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1",
    "name": "TeamTest3",
    "ownerid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1"
},    
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897395\"",
    "teamid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TeamTest2",
    "ownerid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894835\"",
    "teamid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078",
    "name": "kalinin-staging",
    "ownerid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078"
}
```

Actual result

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897395\"",
    "teamid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TeamTest2",
    "ownerid": "7a526c62-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894834\"",
    "teamid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781",
    "name": "TestingPl13",
    "ownerid": "58ab8076-f4ae-e711-8107-480fcff22781"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"897396\"",
    "teamid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1",
    "name": "TeamTest3",
    "ownerid": "8e4fcd11-53aa-e711-8105-70106fa1c9b1"
},
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"894835\"",
    "teamid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078",
    "name": "kalinin-staging",
    "ownerid": "be7da7fb-178f-e711-8118-c4346bc51078"
}
```

It seems that just TeamTest2 is not getting sorted, but I still can't find out why.

Comment: Did you try rearranging $select first and then $orderby

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes I did. Actually, at first I put select before orderby.

Comment: Are you expecting order by name asc when you put accountid asc ??

Comment: @ArunVinoth If I put accountid asc then I get result sorted by accountid as normal. Only name does not work as I expected.

Comment: Update your question with sample data, exact query & expected result vs actual

Comment: @ArunVinoth ok done.